# Why is Docker useful when running builds on slave nodes?

Tags: jenkins, docker

Why is Docker useful when running jenkin builds on slave nodes? Why is this [Jenkins Docker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) necessary?

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is Docker useful when running jenkin builds on slave nodes?

Because you don't always have enough slave ready to process those jobs.
And the ones that can run your job might run others as well, with potential side-effect (like a concurrent access to a shared resource)

In other words: **provisioning and isolation**.

By running a job inside a docker slave container, you are making sure that job isn't influenced by any other jobs, and has a slave spawn on demand to process it.